# How to merge rows in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have some data in gridview as below.

[image]

I want to merge the rows in gridview as below.

[image]

I already tried with below code in RowDataBound() and PreRender(), the result is not the same as I want.

```
for (int rowIndex = GridView1.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
{
    GridViewRow gvRow = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
    GridViewRow gvPreviousRow = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex + 1];
    for (int cellCount = 0; cellCount < gvRow.Cells.Count; cellCount++)
    {
        if (gvRow.Cells[cellCount].Text ==
                            gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Text)
        {
            if (gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan < 2)
            {
                gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan =
                    gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan + 1;
            }
            gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

In aspx,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="100%"
    AutoGenerateColumns = "false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#fffccc" HeaderStyle-ForeColor ="#ffffff" 
    HeaderStyle-BackColor = "#333" AllowPaging ="true" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" PageSize = "20"
    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnPreRender="GridView1_PreRender">
    <HeaderStyle Height="30px" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Client Company">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblClientCompany" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClientCompany")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Position">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPosition" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Position")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Candidate">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCandidate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Candidate")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Status")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#fffccc"  />
</asp:GridView>
```

Please help me becasue I have no idea. Thanks.

Comment: Whats result when you run your code?

Comment: only the first row is displayed when I run my code.

Comment: @SandarMinAye Post your aspx gridview code

Comment: @VigneshKumar, I already put gridview code in my post.

Comment: @SandarMinAye I have added my answer. Please check and let me know

Comment: For what it's worth, that's not a merge so much as converting to a hierarchical view of the data. GridView's don't really work too well with hierarchical data. As an alternative you may want to look into using a Hierarchical Control like a TreeView or maybe a 3rd party control that provides a Hierarchical GridView

Answer (score 5):

You need to try the method in `DataBound` not  `RowDataBound`

`DataBound` fires after the GridView control binds to a data source(after all rows bound).

`RowDataBound` fires for each row, when a data row is bound to data in a GridView control.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="100%"
    AutoGenerateColumns = "false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#fffccc" HeaderStyle-ForeColor ="#ffffff" 
    HeaderStyle-BackColor = "#333" AllowPaging ="true"  OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound1" PageSize = "20"
    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
    <HeaderStyle Height="30px" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Client Company">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblClientCompany" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClientCompany")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Position">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPosition" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Position")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Candidate">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCandidate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Candidate")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Status")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#fffccc"  />
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    for (int rowIndex = GridView1.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
    {
        GridViewRow gvRow = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
        GridViewRow gvPreviousRow = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex + 1];
        for (int cellCount = 0; cellCount < gvRow.Cells.Count; cellCount++)
        {
            if (gvRow.Cells[cellCount].Text ==
                                gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Text)
            {
                if (gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan < 2)
                {
                    gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan =
                        gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan + 1;
                }
                gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did u change ondatabound?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Vignesh Kumar, the processing can be done in the `DataBound` event, after all the rows have been populated.

In order to retrieve the fields values, I suggest adding them to the `DataKeyNames` attribute of the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ClientCompany,Position" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" ... />
```

Here is the code to combine the cells:

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int currentRowIndex = 0; currentRowIndex < GridView1.Rows.Count; currentRowIndex++)
    {
        GridViewRow currentRow = GridView1.Rows[currentRowIndex];
        CombineColumnCells(currentRow, 0, "ClientCompany");
        CombineColumnCells(currentRow, 1, "Position");
    }
}

private void CombineColumnCells(GridViewRow currentRow, int colIndex, string fieldName)
{
    TableCell currentCell = currentRow.Cells[colIndex];

    if (currentCell.Visible)
    {
        Object currentValue = GridView1.DataKeys[currentRow.RowIndex].Values[fieldName];

        for (int nextRowIndex = currentRow.RowIndex + 1; nextRowIndex < GridView1.Rows.Count; nextRowIndex++)
        {
            Object nextValue = GridView1.DataKeys[nextRowIndex].Values[fieldName];

            if (nextValue.ToString() == currentValue.ToString())
            {
                GridViewRow nextRow = GridView1.Rows[nextRowIndex];
                TableCell nextCell = nextRow.Cells[colIndex];
                currentCell.RowSpan = Math.Max(1, currentCell.RowSpan) + 1;
                nextCell.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created for first column in vb.net code behind:

Note: Column should be BoundField.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID">
      <ItemStyle Width="70px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

VB.Net code behind:

```
Private Sub gvGridView_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gvGridView.DataBound

    Dim rowCount As Integer = gvTranscript1.Rows.Count
    Dim RowIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim gvRow As GridViewRow
    Dim gvPrevRow As GridViewRow
    Dim cellIndex As Integer = 0

    For RowIndex = rowCount - 2 To 0 Step -1
        gvRow = gvTranscript1.Rows(RowIndex) 'second last
        gvPrevRow = gvTranscript1.Rows(RowIndex + 1) 'last
        'lblmsg.Text += gvRow.Cells(0).Text & " - " & gvPrevRow.Cells(0).Text & "<br>"
        If gvRow.Cells(0).Text = gvPrevRow.Cells(0).Text Then
            If gvPrevRow.Cells(cellIndex).RowSpan < 2 Then

                gvRow.Cells(cellIndex).RowSpan = 2

            Else

                gvRow.Cells(cellIndex).RowSpan = gvPrevRow.Cells(cellIndex).RowSpan + 1

            End If
            gvPrevRow.Cells(0).Visible = False
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow).Union(GridView2.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow)).ToArray().Select(Function(f) New With {.YourColumn1 = f.Cells(0).Text, .YourColumn2 = f.Cells(1).Text, .YourColumnN = f.Cells(n).Text})
GridView1.DataSource = rows
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove ItemTemplate and take boundField Columns