# Merging Repeater Rows with same Column values in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#

Below code I'm using for gridview to merge rows with same values attached is the output in the image.
I want to get the same output but using repeater control,so please anyone help me in modifying the below code for Repeater control,Thanks in advance

```
 **protected void grd_popup_details_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        int RowSpan = 2;
        for (int i = grd_popup_details.Rows.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            GridViewRow currRow = grd_popup_details.Rows[i];
            GridViewRow prevRow = grd_popup_details.Rows[i + 1];
            if (currRow.Cells[0].Text == prevRow.Cells[0].Text)
            {
                currRow.Cells[0].RowSpan = RowSpan;
                prevRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
                RowSpan += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                RowSpan = 2;
            }
        }
    }**
```

[image]

Comment: this question has been asked before [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642431/how-to-merge-rows-in-gridview)

Comment: yeah it was asked before but it was for Gridview,i want in Repeater control